# Serving static files with Apache and Daphne

Tags: apache, django-channels, daphne

I'm trying to learn to use django-channels and have worked through both the tutorial and [this multichat example](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/multichat). I am now trying to deploy it on a Digital Ocean droplet using Apache and Daphne.

I have 2 issues:

1. my static files are not getting used (I have run collectstatic)
2. I can only get Daphne working when I type in `daphne
   multichat.asgi:application --port 8001 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2` rather
   than using the `daphne.service` file below

This is my `Apache` conf file which I hoped would serve the static files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@hexiawebservices.co.uk
    ServerName multichat.hexiawebservices.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.multichat.hexiawebservices.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/multichat

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8001/

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/multichat/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/multichat/static/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /var/www/multichat/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/multichat/static/

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/multichat>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my `/etc/systemd/system/daphne.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon for multichat
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/multichat/multichat
ExecStart=/var/www/multichat/env/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 multichat.asgi:application

# Not sure if should use 'on-failure' or 'always'. 
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**EDIT 1**

As requested, here is `routing.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from channels.http import AsgiHandler
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path("chat/stream/", ChatConsumer),
        ]),
    ),

})
```

An `consumers.py`

```
from django.conf import settings

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer

from .exceptions import ClientError
from .utils import get_room_or_error


class ChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    """
    This chat consumer handles websocket connections for chat clients.

    It uses AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer, which means all the handling functions
    must be async functions, and any sync work (like ORM access) has to be
    behind database_sync_to_async or sync_to_async. For more, read
    http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html
    """

    ##### WebSocket event handlers

    async def connect(self):
        """
        Called when the websocket is handshaking as part of initial connection.
        """
        # Are they logged in?
        if self.scope["user"].is_anonymous:
            # Reject the connection
            await self.close()
        else:
            # Accept the connection
            await self.accept()
        # Store which rooms the user has joined on this connection
        self.rooms = set()

    async def receive_json(self, content):
        """
        Called when we get a text frame. Channels will JSON-decode the payload
        for us and pass it as the first argument.
        """
        # Messages will have a "command" key we can switch on
        command = content.get("command", None)
        try:
            if command == "join":
                # Make them join the room
                await self.join_room(content["room"])
            elif command == "leave":
                # Leave the room
                await self.leave_room(content["room"])
            elif command == "send":
                await self.send_room(content["room"], content["message"])
        except ClientError as e:
            # Catch any errors and send it back
            await self.send_json({"error": e.code})

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        """
        Called when the WebSocket closes for any reason.
        """
        # Leave all the rooms we are still in
        for room_id in list(self.rooms):
            try:
                await self.leave_room(room_id)
            except ClientError:
                pass

    ##### Command helper methods called by receive_json

    async def join_room(self, room_id):
        """
        Called by receive_json when someone sent a join command.
        """
        # The logged-in user is in our scope thanks to the authentication ASGI middleware
        room = await get_room_or_error(room_id, self.scope["user"])
        # Send a join message if it's turned on
        if settings.NOTIFY_USERS_ON_ENTER_OR_LEAVE_ROOMS:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                room.group_name,
                {
                    "type": "chat.join",
                    "room_id": room_id,
                    "username": self.scope["user"].username,
                }
            )
        # Store that we're in the room
        self.rooms.add(room_id)
        # Add them to the group so they get room messages
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            room.group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        # Instruct their client to finish opening the room
        await self.send_json({
            "join": str(room.id),
            "title": room.title,
        })

    async def leave_room(self, room_id):
        """
        Called by receive_json when someone sent a leave command.
        """
        # The logged-in user is in our scope thanks to the authentication ASGI middleware
        room = await get_room_or_error(room_id, self.scope["user"])
        # Send a leave message if it's turned on
        if settings.NOTIFY_USERS_ON_ENTER_OR_LEAVE_ROOMS:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                room.group_name,
                {
                    "type": "chat.leave",
                    "room_id": room_id,
                    "username": self.scope["user"].username,
                }
            )
        # Remove that we're in the room
        self.rooms.discard(room_id)
        # Remove them from the group so they no longer get room messages
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            room.group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        # Instruct their client to finish closing the room
        await self.send_json({
            "leave": str(room.id),
        })

    async def send_room(self, room_id, message):
        """
        Called by receive_json when someone sends a message to a room.
        """
        # Check they are in this room
        if room_id not in self.rooms:
            raise ClientError("ROOM_ACCESS_DENIED")
        # Get the room and send to the group about it
        room = await get_room_or_error(room_id, self.scope["user"])
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            room.group_name,
            {
                "type": "chat.message",
                "room_id": room_id,
                "username": self.scope["user"].username,
                "message": message,
            }
        )

    ##### Handlers for messages sent over the channel layer

    # These helper methods are named by the types we send - so chat.join becomes chat_join
    async def chat_join(self, event):
        """
        Called when someone has joined our chat.
        """
        # Send a message down to the client
        await self.send_json(
            {
                "msg_type": settings.MSG_TYPE_ENTER,
                "room": event["room_id"],
                "username": event["username"],
            },
        )

    async def chat_leave(self, event):
        """
        Called when someone has left our chat.
        """
        # Send a message down to the client
        await self.send_json(
            {
                "msg_type": settings.MSG_TYPE_LEAVE,
                "room": event["room_id"],
                "username": event["username"],
            },
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        """
        Called when someone has messaged our chat.
        """
        # Send a message down to the client
        await self.send_json(
            {
                "msg_type": settings.MSG_TYPE_MESSAGE,
                "room": event["room_id"],
                "username": event["username"],
                "message": event["message"],
            },
        )
```

Comment: I've worked out the issue with the service.  I needed to enable it or reboot using `sudo systemctl enable daphne.service`

Comment: I moved my static files to an AWS S3 bucket and I've serving them from there and those are now serving correctly, but I'm now getting this error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://multichat.hexiawebservices.co.uk/chat/stream/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Comment: post the routing and consumer code

Comment: have you installed the Apache module `mod_proxy_wstunnel`?

Comment: yes, `mod_proxy_wstunnel` is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the conf file that sorted it for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@hexiawebservices.co.uk
    ServerName multichat.hexiawebservices.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.multichat.hexiawebservices.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/multichat

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://0.0.0.0:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(ws(/.*)?)$ ws://0.0.0.0:8001/$1
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8001/

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/multichat/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/multichat/static/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /var/www/multichat/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/multichat/static/

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/multichat/multichat>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean the apache server is serving the static files?
The lines bellow are in in your conf file. They mean you must have tried to let the apache server to serve the static files.

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/multichat/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/multichat/static/

<Directory /var/www/multichat/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/multichat/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried that and it doesn't work. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).